# flask-based REST api: marshmallow vs flask-restful

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful, marshmallow

I have gone thru a tone of `flask` tutorials the last couple of weeks.

From my understanding, to build a simple REST api based on `flask`, there are (among others) two ways:

- adopting `flask-restful` and using it to create `Resources` that you then expose via the appropriate url/routes and bind them with `sqlalchemy` models
- use plain `sqlalchemy` for the model, and then `marshmallow` for de/serialization and object serving in `json` format.

Is there a comparison among these two approaches? I 'm kinda new in the field and the `marshmallow` approach seemed to be quicker and perhaps easier to follow.

Are there any benefits when it comes to adopting `flask-restful` compared to the de/serialiation layer of `marshmallow`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marshmallow is a serialization/deserialization library and flask-restful is a package to build REST APIs.

Yes there are some benefits from using flask-restful:

- Easy argument parsing
- Custom error handler
- Encourages REST best practices

There is also a package called Flask-Restplus that is based on Flask-resftul but add some features like Swagger doc generation, better error handling etc: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Does this mean that it is better to use Flask-RESTful or that both modules are compatible and used for different things? Is serialization/deserialization less necessary or less convenient when using Flask-RESTful? Does it make sense to use Marshmallow in a REST API if we're using Flask-Restful?

Comment: This project has been forked to Flask-RESTX and will be maintained by by the python-restx organization. Flask-RESTPlus should be considered unmaintained.
Source: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus